# addClass append every time in every Clone

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my script

```
 var newclass = 0;

 jQuery("#addexperience").click(function(){
    $("#expclone").clone().find("input:text").val("").end().prependTo( ".exp_clone" );
    $(".ongoing").each(function(){
        $(".ongoing").addClass("newclass"+newclass);
        newclass++;
    });
 });
```

I am tring to clonning a perticular div, and add an class on clone element.
but addClass append every time,

means in first clone it added:  newclass1, in second clone it added: newclass1 newclass2; so on..

i want only newclass2 in second clone, and newclass3 in thire clone and so on..

Comment: The php tag seems to be misplaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$(this)` inside the callback of `.each`:

```
$(".ongoing").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("newclass"+newclass);
    newclass++;      
});
```

Or you even don't need the variable `newclass`, `.addClass` accept a function as parameter:

```
$(".ongoing").addClass(function(index) {
  // index is start from 0
  return "newclass" + (index + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var newclass = 0;
jQuery("#addexperience").click(function(){
    $clone=$("#expclone").clone()
    $clone.find("input:text").val("");
    $clone.find(".ongoing").removeAttr('class') // remove all classes
          .addClass('ongoing'); // again add ongoing class
    $clone.find(".ongoing").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("newclass"+newclass);
        newclass++;
    });
    $clone.prependTo(".exp_clone");
});
```

But, is is better to give an new `id` instead of new `class`.

Comment: Thankyou so much, Please, accept my vehement protestation of gratitude, dear….

Answer (score 0):

This is because every time you clone an element, it's going to add the class to each of those elements even though it is already present. What you do is, once you clone the element, get the last cloned element and `addClass` only for that. Remove the `.each()` function and try:

```
$(".ongoing").last().addClass('newClass'+newclass);
newclass++;
```

Comment: Tnankyou For your invaluable advices and devotion, Please, accept my deep appreciation,

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
$(".ongoing").addClass("newclass"+newclass);
```

to:

```
$(".ongoing").removeClass().addClass("newclass"+newclass);
```

it will remove all previous classes of `.ongoing` and add new class in it.
if you want to have `.ongoing` class then try like this:

```
$(".ongoing").removeClass().addClass("ongoing newclass"+newclass);
```

Comment: Tnankyou so much , Please, kindly accept this expression of my cordial thanks to you once again ……