# Button for deleting draggable cloneable DIV elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, interact.js

I want to be able to select cloneable draggable objects (red circles) by left-clicking and then delete them by clicking on the button `Delete selected circle`. I want to enable deleting only those objects that are located INSIDE `.dropzone`.

[Here is my JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ghgvzenk/2/).

The `.dropzone` is a grey-colored `div`, and a draggable object is a red circle.

[image]

This is the code for deleting an object:

```
    function removeObject(div) {
      div.querySelector(".draggable").parentNode.removeChild(elem);
      return false;
    }
```

I pass the class of a cloned object, however, it gets undetected and therefore I cannot delete it. Also I don't know how to limit the deleting operation to only those objects that are inside `.dropzone`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, add a new class to each cloned object so you can tell the difference and pass a class that will be specific to that circle to the remove function. Using this, you could also add a class to the object when dropped, so that way you know if it is in the box and remove when it is dropped outside of the box.

[addClass append every time in every Clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356562/addclass-append-every-time-in-every-clone)

**EDIT:**

Here, this is the relevant changes I made to your fiddle, I only pasted the portions I changes. I commented out some of my code that was unnecessary, but I left it in because it might be of use to you. Feel  free to delete though. Hope this is what you were looking for.

I made it so that the clones get a class of cloned and if they are dropped in the box area, they get a selected class added on. Then if another circle is touched, the selected class is removed and only gets added on if the last circle touched was moved or placed in the box, or in the box. If the circle is removed from the box, it loses the selected class.

```js
  .on('move', function(event) {
    var interaction = event.interaction;
    if (interaction.pointerIsDown && !interaction.interacting() && event.currentTarget.getAttribute('clonable') != 'false') {
      var original = event.currentTarget;
      var clone = event.currentTarget.cloneNode(true);
      var x = clone.offsetLeft;
      var y = clone.offsetTop;
 /*   var length = $(".cloned").length;
      if(length == "0"){
        clone.className = "draggable cloned cloned-0";
      }
      else{       
               clone.className = "draggable cloned cloned-"+length;
      } */
      clone.className = "draggable cloned";
      clone.setAttribute('clonable', 'false');
      clone.style.position = "absolute";
      clone.style.left = original.offsetLeft + "px";
      clone.style.top = original.offsetTop + "px";
      original.parentElement.appendChild(clone);
      interaction.start({
        name: 'drag'
      }, event.interactable, clone);
    }
  })
// enable draggables to be dropped into this
interact('.dropzone').dropzone({
  // Require a 50% element overlap for a drop to be possible
  overlap: 0.50,

  // listen for drop related events:

  ondropactivate: function(event) {
    // add active dropzone feedback
    event.target.classList.add('drop-active');
    $('.cloned').removeClass('selected');
  },
  ondragenter: function(event) {
    var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget,
      dropzoneElement = event.target;

    // feedback the possibility of a drop
    dropzoneElement.classList.add('drop-target');
//     draggableElement.classList.add('in-zone'); 
  },
  ondragleave: function(event) {
    // remove the drop feedback style
//     event.relatedTarget.classList.remove('in-zone');
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
  },
  ondrop: function(event) {
    event.relatedTarget.classList.add('selected');
  },
  ondropdeactivate: function(event) {
    // remove active dropzone feedback
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-active');
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
  }
  
  
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Should I use `jQuery`? Could you please show this approach in my jsfiddle?

Comment: I didn't add the delete functionality, but basically you need to create a function where if the button is clicked, it finds the circle with the selected class and deletes it. That won't be too hard now that it knows what to search for.